# Solidity documentation mint and send function

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

[image: Solidity Documentation]

In the documentation solidity has this coin example, I read the documentation but I couldn't understand what is the difference and purpose of both? What mint and send functions are doing?
The send function makes sense but mint function is confusing.
What is the meaning of "Sends an amount of newly created coins to an address, can only be called by the contract creator"

Answer (score 0):

When the coin contract is deployed, there is nothing to use as long as you create something. The process of creating coins is referred to as minting.

> Sends an amount of newly created coins to an address
> Minting is usually perceived to be sending coins somewhere from nowhere. This may sound confusing but think of it this way:

If you want a regular transfer: address(Alice) sends to address(Bob)

If you have a method to do: address(Nothing) to address(Contract Creator), now you can create coins.

> can only be called by the contract creator

This makes sense since minting creates value out of thin air, and this contract wants to allow no one but the creator.

Comment: Okay it makes sense but still slightly confused.
Can you give some example when mint function is called?
I know minting, but is this mint function rewarding the contract creator or the minter. And also does this mint function reward everytime someone uses the contract? Who gets the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `mint` function, it has this `require` statement:

```
 // msg.sender is the account that calls the function
 require(msg.sender==minter)
```

so only "minter" can call this. "Minter account" will be creating new tokens, burn tokens and distributing the token to other accounts or selling tokens. So contract owner creator and financial admin are separated. You set the `minter` when you deploy the contract:

```
    // you declare the state variable first
    address public _minter;

    // you assign a value during the construction of the contract

    constructor(address minter_){
        _minter=minter_;        
     }
```

In object-oriented programming, `constructor` is called when you create an instance of the class. In solidity we create an instance of contract when we deploy the contract. When we deploy the contract we have to pass this parameter. If you deploy on remix, you would have this:

[image]

you have to enter the minter address into the box.

- `send` function is defined as public, so anyone can call it. In above example, it is just used to send some coin to receiver account.